# Powershell script to stop services and set to manual

Tags: powershell, script, remote

I hope this is in the correct place. I know this question has been asked a lot before but I can't quite find what I need.

I am looking for a script to run on several remote servers at once to stop a particular service if it is running and set it to manual startup.

That bit is the easy part, I would also like it to feedback to me what task its doing and then check the service again after to confirm its stopped and set to manual.

This is what I have so far.

```
##Get user credentials
$credtentials = Get-Credential


##Services
$servicename = 'Spooler'
##Server List
$server = 'myserver'

$service = Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server

if ($service.StartType -eq 'Automatic') {
    $service | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
}
```

Is anyone able to contribute to this please?

Comment: [Stop-Service (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management) - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Hi, yeah thats where I got the basics from but how do I add line to give me feedback and then to check again that the service is manual?

Comment: [Get startup type of Windows service using PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304821/get-startup-type-of-windows-service-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

Create an array variable (`$Servers`) for the server names and pass that to the `-ComputerName` variable of [invoke-command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html). This runs the PowerShell logic  within a `-ScriptBlock` against each machine listed in the array .

This also uses the credential you enter in and with that credential it runs the invoked commands within the script block as that security context against all those servers.

It will set the `StartType` to `Manual` if it's set to `Automatic`, and it will stop the service if its status if `Running`. Afterwards, it will output the remote server name, the service `Name`, the `Status`, and the `StartType`.

Please note this assumes the credential you put into the `$credential` variable has admin access to each server you run the remote commands against; adjust `$servers` list accordingly per run.

### PowerShell

```
$credentials = Get-Credential;
$Servers = "server0004","server0982";
$servicename = 'Spooler';

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock {
    $service = Get-Service -Name $args[0];
    If($service.StartType -eq 'Automatic'){$service | Set-Service -StartupType Manual};
    If($service.Status -eq 'Running'){$service | Stop-Service -Force};
    $service = Get-Service -Name $args[0];
    $service | Select @{n="Server"; e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Status, Name, StartType | FT
    } -ArgumentList $servicename -Credential $credentials;
```

#### Output

```
Server      Status Name    StartType
------      ------ ----    ---------
server0982 Stopped Spooler    Manual



Server      Status Name    StartType
------      ------ ----    ---------
server0004 Stopped Spooler    Manual
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)

  > `-ArgumentList Object[]`
  >
  > Set local variables in the command.
  > The variables in the command are replaced by these values before the command is run on
  > the remote computer. Enter the values in a comma-separated list.
  > Values are associated with variables in the order that they are listed. The alias for ArgumentList is "Args".
- [Stop-Service](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-service.html)